# How can I see all opened pull requests on command line?

Tags: git, command-line, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I have a repo stored on BitBucket and cloned locally, I want to know via command line if that repo has pull requests open in order to invoke that command via shell script. Do you know if that command exists?

Comment: Pull requests is not something that `git` by itself handles at all, but more a function of the hosting websites, such as github or bitbucket, does for you. I don't think you'll find any such command line tool unless someone has made an extension/plugin to git that handles a specific website, such as bitbucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @lasse-v-karlsen said pull requests are not git features. You could use the [Bitbucket CLI](https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SCLI/Examples) or the [Bitbucket API](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Busername%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/pullrequests) via a curl/wget request.

e.g.: The below will return a page of pull-request titles, with total no of pull-requests.

```
curl \
   https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/{username}/{repo_slug}/pullrequests \
   | \
   jq "{ \
       pagelen: .pagelen, \
       size: .size, \
       titles: [.values[].title], \
       pageindex: .page \
   }"
```

*I am using [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) to parse json object*